# Integrating facebook with my web app

Tags: facebook, twitter, spring-social

I am implementing a news sharing website for my university project. Users of my app will be provided with a list of news articles with customize shared button named "Show your friend". Almost exactly requirements can be seen on www.pulse.me . And, the way i want to implement is, when the share button is click, there will be a popup asking users if they want to also share on twitter, G+ and other social networks. And also the popup should be customize js popup rather than facebook default blue one. Can I implement it easily? I also need to access user profile on facebook, so i am planning to use Spring social (although not sure if i really need it or not). As a summary, my questions are

- Do i need facebook app
- Do i need user logined to their facebook account (and authorize my app)
- Should i use spring-social (to implement something like pulse.me)

Any suggestion would be really appreciated as i am very new to spring social facebook integration and quite confuse how to implement such a functionality in my project.

regards
Yewint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you need to change the default to something custom, you need to implement it yourself or extend what is present. Same is here, you want to display a custom share window, for which you will have to create a Facebook app and ask user to lo into the same with `publish_actions` permission.

As far as use of spring-social is involved, its up to you. You may use spring social and start your work directly on integrating with your application or you may skip it altogether and build the requests, for `oauth`, posting yourself and maintaining sessions and gain a little more as how this all interaction is done, but remember its not a wise idea to reinvent the wheel.
So as a summary,

- You are required to create a Facebook app because of the customization involved
- You will be required to authorize the application with `publish_actions` permission to post on behalf of user.
- You may use spring-social to start early with your application.

Comment: So i can start with default share button without needing to implement anything explicitly. It will save my project deadline for now. Later I can create facebook app and integrate with my website to do sharing process on behalf of user. Thanks alot for your help.